# ShareMediaTask only working in debug mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-debugging

Normally I tend not to ask on StackOverflow before having done debugging for at least 2 days. But this time, it's not possible to debug this. So this is what I'm trying to achive:

- The user presses the shutter button and a photo is captured.
- The app goes to a second screen enableling the user to post-process the image, save to image library and **to share it with their friends using the ShareMediaTask**

So using this code:

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
if (pic == null)
{
    using (MemoryStream saveStream = new MemoryStream(imagedata))
    {
        saveStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        pic = library.SavePicture("camera.NET_image_" + System.Environment.TickCount, saveStream);
        saveStream.Close();
    }
}
ShareMediaTask shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
shareMediaTask.FilePath = pic.GetPath();
shareMediaTask.Show();
```

As you can see, the picture is saved to the pictures hub if it wasn't done already (by using the save button. And the saving works just fine. So I just don't understand why it crashes when not in debug mode and works fine in debug mode.

The only hint I have is an excpetion thrown when starting the sharetask (but the share task still works and my friends actually has confirmed he had recived all the images.

Fore somebody with really much time, here is the unbelivably (at least for me and I claim not to be a complete c# noob) long stacktrace:

```
at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
at System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Position()
at WriteMemoryStreamToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
at WriteKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
at WriteArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(Stream stream, Object graph)
at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.BaseStreamPersister.Serialize(IDictionary`2 dictionary, IEnumerable`1 knownTypes)
at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.SaveState()
at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.FireDeactivated(UInt32 reason)
at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.ITask.Pause.Invoke(UInt32 reason)
at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.Task.FireOnPause(UInt32 reason)
```

While it sounds easily understandable that there's a stream that can't be accessed, can somebody tell me what type of stream they mean? Because at least in my user code, there isn't any streamwork done other than saving the image (and that succeeds, as I saw in the pictures hub easily)

Comment: can you try to take out the saveStream.Close() and see?.... on further thinking.... do you have a IFDEBUG statement anywhere in the code?

Comment: IFDEBUG: nether used it anywhere. Removing saveStream.Close() doesn't change anything, eigther.

Comment: I think I've seen similar problems on WP apps. I think the problem was that in Release mode, there are stricter rules for e.g. how long an operation may take. I think you can still debug apps in release mode, or at least set break points; can you check on which line it fails?